# Field validation not working in Rendering Parameter Template for MVC form

Tags: sitecore-forms, content-editor, validation, field, rendering-parameters

I've assigned a `Parameter Template` in the MVC form rendering called `Redirect Parameters` `(/sitecore/layout/Renderings/System/Forms/Mvc Form)` as shown in below screnshot

[image]

Within this `template`, I've created a `Multilist with Search field` as shown in below screenshot.

[image]

And in the `RedirectDataSource` field item, I've added the following `Validation`:
[image]

It must allow the selection of just one value.

However, it's not working. There's no message, nor an error message. It looks like I didn't set up any `validation`. Also, I've assigned this same `Validation` for a regular Template, and it works fine.
So I have no idea why it's not working.

Is there anyone who faced this same issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use a different approach to do this. I have verified this by creating the same scenario according to your question.

1. You need to go under `Validation Rules` using the path `/sitecore/system/Settings/Validation Rules` and need to create a new `Validation Rule`. The type should be `RegexValidator` Refer to the screenshot below.

[image]

2. Then you need to go to your `rendering parameter` field and apply that rule under the `Validation Rules` section like this.

[image]

And when you select more than one value in the field in your `rendering parameter`, then you can see the `validation` in the `red bar` on the left and `red dots` on the right top.

[image]

And if you want to see the alert message, then I think you need to do some customizations.

Hope this help.